# How to aggregate (sum) rows by first column value in a multi-columns .tsv file using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sum, aggregate

There are several examples out there, but always for files with only one column to be aggregated, e.g.

```
awk '{arr[$1]+=$2;} END {for (i in arr) print i, arr[i]}' filename
```

How do I perform the same but for a file with hundreds of columns? The output should be also for those hundreds of columns.

Input

```
a 1 2 4 1 ...
b 1 2 1 2 ...
b 2 1 1 1 ...
```

Output

```
a 1 2 4 1 ...
b 3 3 2 3 ...
```

Comment: you can use multi-arrays with `gawk`

Answer (score 3):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) as follows :

```
awk '{                                 # Call awk
       b[$1];                          # array b with index being first field 

       for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)              # loop from 2nd field to last field, NF gives total no of fields in record/line
       a[$1,i]+=$i                     # array a where index being first field SUBSEP and current value of i
                                       # $i gives current field value,
                                       # using += value will be summed whenever it encounters with same array index

     }

 END{                                  # end block here we process 
      for( i in b)                     # loop through array b
      {
          printf("%s",i)               # print index value which forms  1st column
          for(j=2;j<=NF;j++)           # loop through 2nd field to last field
          {
             printf("%s%s",OFS,a[i,j]) # print o/p sep and array element
          } 
          print "";                    # print new line
      } 
    }' file
```

**One-liner**

```
awk '{ b[$1]; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[$1,i]+=$i }END{for( i in b){printf("%s",i);for(j=2;j<=NF;j++){printf("%s%s",OFS,a[i,j])} print ""}}' file
```

**Input**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat file
a 1 2 4 1
b 1 2 1 2
b 2 1 1 1
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ awk '{ 
       b[$1]; 
       for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
       a[$1,i]+=$i 
     }
 END{
      for( i in b)
      {
          printf("%s",i)
          for(j=2;j<=NF;j++)
          {
              printf("%s%s",OFS,a[i,j])
          } 
          print "";
      } 
    }' file
a 1 2 4 1
b 3 3 2 3
```

**If first field of your file is sorted then**

```
awk '
function print_and_clear(i,j)
{
      for( i in b)
      {
          printf("%s",i)
          for(j=2;j<=NF;j++)
          {
              printf("%s%s",OFS,a[i,j])
          } 
          print "";
      } 
    split("",a)
    split("",b)
}
p!=$1{
  if(i){
    print_and_clear()
  }
  p = $1
}
{
    b[$1]
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)
    a[$1,i]+=$i
}
END{
    print_and_clear()
}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk when the `file` is sorted by the first field:

```
awk '
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                              # iterate all fields
        if($1!=p) {                                 # when $1 changes
            if(NR>1)                                # ... after first record
                printf "%s%s",s[i],(i==NF?ORS:OFS)  # ... output
            s[i]=$i                                 # and reset s
        }
        else                                        # when $1 remains the same
            if(i>1)
                s[i]+=$i                            # sum fields but not the first
    p=$1                                            # remember the key field
}
END{                                                # special last condition print
    printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
        printf "%s%s",s[i],(i==NF?ORS:OFS)
}
' file
a 1 2 4 1
b 3 3 2 3
```